# junitlauncher, tests are not executed when using "testclasses" instead of test

Tags: ant, junit5

If I use the below then my tests are executing fine:

```
<target name="testing_junit5_A" depends="compile" description="TODO">
    <junitlauncher printsummary="true">
        <classpath refid="run.classpath" />
        <test name="mypackage.myclass" />
    </junitlauncher>
</target>
```

But I don't want to specify every test class. So instead I'm trying:

```
<target name="testing_junit5_B" depends="compile" description="TODO">   
    <fileset id="test_files" dir="C:\mypath">
        <include name="myclass.class"/>
    </fileset>
    <echo message="Looking for tests in files: ${toString:test_files}" />

    <junitlauncher printsummary="true">
        <classpath refid="run.classpath" />
        <testclasses>
            <fileset refid="test_files"/>
        </testclasses>  
    </junitlauncher>
</target>
```

But no tests are executed. The expected test (.class) file are included in the fileset and I have triple checked that C:\mypath\myclass.class is the only myclass.class file and that the fully qualified class name is mypackage.myclass. (With path, package name and class name replaced in this example.)

Ant version is 1.10.11. In both cases there is also a "Failed to launch in-vm tests" message, but I guess that is not related.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the reason.
After adding `<fork dir="${basedir}" />` I got some more helpful exception stack trace.
It seems I didn't understand the fileset correctly. I thought fileset "dir" and "include name" were simply used to construct a path, but it seems that "include name" is also used to construct a package name. So it was looking for class "part_of_path.myactualpackage.myclass". After moving the first part of "include name" to "dir" it works better.